# MVC Razor View: How to render a list of text boxes for a List<Task> in the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a `List<Task>` in my model. This list contains 2 tasks(say) in it

```
public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

public class Task    {
    public Task()
    {
        Title="";
        Total= 0;
    }

    public string Title{ get; set; }

    public int Total{ get; set; }
}
```

Now in my razor view, I want render 2 text boxes for each of the `Tasks` in the `List<Tasks>` of my model.

I didn't loop, just placed direct text boxes like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[0].Title, new { @maxlength = "50"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[0].Total, new { @maxlength = "2"})
<br>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[1].Title, new { @maxlength = "50"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[1].Total, new { @maxlength = "2"})
```

This renders the form fine, but clicking the submit button doesn't do anything in FF.
However it posts fine in IE9.

View source shows this html generated like this:

```
<input id="Tasks_0__Title" maxlength="50" name="Tasks[0].Title" type="text" value="" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Total must be a number." data-val-required="The Total field is required." id="Tasks_0__Total" maxlength="2" name="Tasks[0].Total" type="text" value="" />
```

This HTML doesn't look right. It has `name="Tasks[0].Total"` which seems odd.

How should I do this so that I can access the text box values from `List<>` in my controller after post?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I just kept one row for test. This is the html I see in FF.

```
<input id="Tasks_0__Title" type="text" value="" name="Tasks[0].Title" maxlength="50">
<input id="Tasks_0__Total" type="text" value="" name="Tasks[0].Total" maxlength="2" data-val-required="The Total field is required." data-val-number="The field Total must be a number." data-val="true">
```

This doesn't post when I click the submit button.

Now if I change `name="Tasks[0].Title" to name="Tasks_0__Title" and name="Tasks_0__Total"`
 in FIREBUG it posts fine.

If I delete name completely it also posts fine in FF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Tasks[0].Total` and `Tasks[1].Total` instead of `Items`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[0].Title, new { @maxlength = "50"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[0].Total, new { @maxlength = "2"})
<br/>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[1].Title, new { @maxlength = "50"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tasks[1].Total, new { @maxlength = "2"})
```

`name="Tasks[0].Total"` is not odd. That's exactly how the input should be named in order for the model binder to fetch the value back in the POST action. See [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for the wire format used by the default model binder when dealing with lists and dictionaries.

This being said I would recommend you using editor templates => instead of writing those 5 lines of code in your view replace them with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tasks)
```

and then inside the corresponding editor template (`~/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/Task.cshtml`) which will be automatically rendered for each element in the `Tasks` collection:

```
@model Task
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @maxlength = "50"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Total, new { @maxlength = "2"})    
<br/>
```

Now you can leave the editor templates worry about proper naming convention, etc...

As far as your POST action is concerned:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.Tasks should be correctly bound here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Darin, Are you sure that name="Tasks[0].Total" is NOT odd? I just tested in FF. With these FF doesn't post to server if I click Submit button. If I change all the names in Firebug from Tasks[0].Total to Tasks_0__Total then it posts fine. Generated ids look like Tasks_0__Total, Tasks_1__Total but which are fine but the names has [0] in their name. Any way to exclude the name generation?

Comment: @Projapati, the ids doesn't matter. It's the `name` attribute which is used to send to the server. And the correct name is `Tasks[0].Total` as explained in the [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) from Scott Hanselman I've linked to.

Comment: Name = ListName[index].PropertyName bombs out in FF 4.0.1 Html.BeginForm() is not getting posted if I click the submit button. If I change the name to use underscore instead of [0] it posts. Any reason?

Comment: @Projapati, no reason, works fine for me. What *bombs out*? Are you getting an error message or something?

Comment: I meant clicking the submit button doesn't do anything. The button is dead in FF, Chrome, Opera. But works in IE9.

Comment: @Projapati, what about FireBug? Any net activity? Any errors in the console? There must be something. I cannot help as I don't know what is your code. As I said, I have created a sample example which worked perfectly fine for me. Maybe you have some other scripts that interfere?

Comment: Darin, I found something. See data-val-required="The Total field is required." in the html source of the second text box. This makes it required field in FF. But same html is not making it required in IE. Interesting. So if I put some value in 2nd box, it submits in FF

Comment: @Projapati, yes you probably have enabled client side validation. Then if your model is invalid the form won't submit. Do you have the jquery validate and jquery validate unobtrusive scripts referenced?

Comment: I have jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js referenced in the base master layout. But I have not made it required in model. Why browsers are behaving differently?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have multiple elements with textboxes.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count; i++)
                            {
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelIem => Model.Students[i].StudentId)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Students[i].Student.FirstNames)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Students[i].Student.LastNames)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Students[i].Score, new { @type = "number" })
                                    </td>
</tr> }
```

This is the ViewModel

```
public class MyModel 
{
 public List<StudentGrade> Students { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentGrade {
        public ApplicationUser Student { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 100)]
        public int? Score { get; set; } = null;
        public string Description { get; set; } = null;
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
    }
```

At the End it will look like this.
[image]