# How do I pass a list from a view to a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view and inside I'm generating a list but I'm not being able to successfully pass it to the controller without the fields being null:

code on my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFOP", "Revenue", null,  FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
              <table class="grid" style="margin-top: 15px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>FOP</th>
                            <th>ORGN</th>
                            <th>PROGRAM</th>
                            <th>PERCENTAGE</th>
                            <th></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>               
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.editBillingFOPList.Count;i++ )
                        { 

                         <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("FOPList[" + @i + "].Fund", 
                                                Model.editBillingFOPList[i].Fund)</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("FOPList[" + @i + "].ORGN", 
                                                Model.editBillingFOPList[i].ORGN)</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("FOPList[" + @i + "].Program", 
                                                Model.editBillingFOPList[i].Program)</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("FOPList[" + @i + "].Percentage", 
                                                Model.editBillingFOPList[i].Percentage)</td>
                        </tr>
```

this is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddFOP(List<BillingFOPModel> FOPList)
        {


            return View();
        }
```

my FOPList shows a count of 1 and if I expand it on debug mode it shows the list of the model but with null values - any thoughts?

My Model:

```
 public class BillingFOPModel
    {
        public string BillingArea;
        public string BillingAreaName;
        public string Fund;
        public string ORGN;
        public string Program;
        public string Percentage;
    }
```

This my ViewModel:

```
  public class EditBillingViewModel
        {   //declare attributes

            public List<BillingFOPModel> editBillingFOPList { get; set; }
            public string newBillingArea { get; set; }
            public string newBillingAreaName { get; set; }
            public string newFund { get; set; }
            public string newORGN { get; set; }
            public string newProgram { get; set; }
            public string newPercentage { get; set; }

            public EditBillingViewModel()
            {

            }

            //constructor that passes a list and 2 strings
            public EditBillingViewModel(List<BillingFOPModel> editBillingFOPList, string newBillingArea, string newBillingAreaName)
            {
                this.editBillingFOPList = editBillingFOPList;
                this.newBillingArea = newBillingArea;
                this.newBillingAreaName = newBillingAreaName;
            }
```

Comment: why aren't you using TextBoxFor like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135277/mvc-razor-view-how-to-render-a-list-of-text-boxes-for-a-listtask-in-the-model)?  You're doing this the very hard way

Comment: show your model class ``BillingFOPModel``

Comment: @Jonesy I'm not sure I can achieve what I need by not iterating

Comment: @EhsanSajjad done both model and viewmodel

Comment: @Jonesy okay I see what you mean - that way seems simpler though due to time constrains I think I'll just do it this way since it seems to be working now  but thanks a lot for shining light on the matter!

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Sir you were right - I screwed up by not setting up the accessors on the model - this is working now , at least I'm fetching the values and they're no longer NULL thanks a ton!! :)

Comment: And why on earth are you not just passing back the model - `public EditBillingViewModelEditBillingViewModel model) {`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing same mistake that new developers of mvc do mostly, your model has fields not properties so thats why you are not getting data posted.

Change fields to properties in your Model class:

```
public class BillingFOPModel
{
    public string BillingArea {get; set; }
    public string BillingAreaName { get; set;}
    public string Fund { get; set;}
    public string ORGN { get; set;}
    public string Program {get; set;}
    public string Percentage {get; set;}
}
```

### SideNote:

Always use strongly typed helpers like `TextBoxFor()`, `DropDownListFor()` whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Using EditorTemplates means you don't need to have a for loop in your mark up therefore not having to worry so much about setting the correct name and id's on controls.